# How to cause the only element created to fade in

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my function that create Note in the dom , the problem is  that for the note create I add class animation "fade in", when  this function run it do the animation for all notes dom and  not only for the one create.
how can I fix it that only the one create will do the animation?

```js
function createNote(note){
    const noteContainer = document.querySelector("#note-display");
    let noteEl = `<div id="${note.id}" class="note fade-in">
                            <span onclick="removeNote(this)" class="remove-container">
                                <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                            </span>
                            <textarea onchange="updateMessage(this)">${note.message}</textarea>
                            <p>${note.date}</p>
                            <p>${note.time}</p>   
                    </div>`
    noteContainer.innerHTML += noteEl;
        console.log(noteContainer.innerHTML)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `insertAdjacentHTML`[Mozilla MDN insertAdjacementHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

Your function should look more like:

```
function createNote(note){
    const noteContainer = document.querySelector("#note-display");
    let noteEl = `<div id="${note.id}" class="note fade-in">
                            <span onclick="removeNote(this)" class="remove-container">
                                <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                            </span>
                            <textarea onchange="updateMessage(this)">${note.message}</textarea>
                            <p>${note.date}</p>
                            <p>${note.time}</p>   
                    </div>`

    noteContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', noteEl);
}
```

Bear in mind that insertAdjacentHTML may not be well suited for user input without some previous html scaping as it is inserted as raw html. From the docs:

```
When inserting HTML into a page by using insertAdjacentHTML(), be careful not to use user input that hasn't been escaped.

It is not recommended you use insertAdjacentHTML() when inserting plain text; instead, use the Node.textContent property or the Element.insertAdjacentText() method. This doesn't interpret the passed content as HTML, but instead inserts it as raw text.
```